# Как сортировать название языков в Polylang?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как в Polylang сделать первый язык EN(английский) , а второй RU?
В настройках в поле "Положение языка в переключателе" на английский ставлю значение 0 , на русский 1 , но всё равно первый язык идет русский

Comment: А как выводится переключатель? Может, вывод сделан как-то "странно", что не позволят использовать сортировки, указанную в поле *Order*?